# Enable VPN usage only for specific applications

Tags: c++, windows, vpn

I have a VPN application which is written in C++ for Windows 7+ and uses OpenVPN as well as RAS for establishing connections and I need to allow only for some apps to be able to use vpn connection and others to use user's default connection/network (I also don't know what apps it will be, users need to configure it). So far I haven't found any hints on how to implement it, is it possible to do it at all on Windows? And if yes, how?

Comment: That's not really a programming question but one of MS Windows administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can *do* that.  VPNs basically work like a secure TCP/IP router (or switch).  They provide an IP-address on each side that is a "gateway" to the network on the other side.  (Appropriate `route` commands must have been issued on both sides, which the VPN client software can do for its local machine.)  I don't think that there is any way to restrict which *applications* can use a particular IP-address . . . but of course I could be mistaken. *(MS-Windows does have many tricks up its sleeve.)*

I think that you should take this to `superuser.com` or some other StackExchange site which is targeted towards system administration of a Windows environment, because your question is actually quite specific to that, and not to VPNs in general.